# java VTD-Parser Logic

Tags: java, xml, parsing, vtd-xml

I implemented VTD-Parser in java which successfully parsed XML file of around 500 MB easily and was able to write in an excel.
I understand that DOM parser first created a tree node structure and then get the data, and SAX is an event based parser. But what makes VTD parse the file so easy and efficient? 
I tried to search, I got many examples of implementation but never got the logic .I tried the below link to get the idea but did not get the clear picture.
[VTD_Parser](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)

If any one can explain the brief idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML) on the subject, VTD-XML (Virtual Token Descriptor for XML) utilizes non exctractive parsing, meaning it does not extract the data out of the document into some memory based data-structure, but rather builds a data structure that contains pointers (in the form of offset and length) to the original document.  This processing is clearly the most memory efficient, but I believe it comes at the cost of performance since the inevitable IO operation is done when the data is requested (but caching can help a lot here).

It seems to me that tis processing is most usefull when the input is very big and the requested data is very small (kind of data mining scenario)

Comment: @Bhavik That is inaccurate, Vtd-xml is better suited for heavy navigation than DOM, and involves virtually no IO cost ... the truth is that extracting data out into data structure is all but a waste of processing power and memory... I would be glad to clarify more...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author - so what makes parse the file so easy and efficiently?

Comment: In short, building DOM tree (e.g. instantiating nodes, strings, and attributes) are fundamentally unnecessary, and often adversely affect XML parsing... VTD-XML circumvents those by using persist addressing scheme called VTD (virtual token descriptor)... there are numerous articles that you can find on the web on the benefits virtues of vtd.